# Using javascript to capture audio data

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I am trying to use the sample code given [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bv55z5fe/324/).

to make something working of my own, namely capture sound from a web page.

I would like to know how setup my files.

I tried to use one html file and inside:

```
<head>
    <javascript>
```

and:

```
    </javascript>
</head>
```

put the javascript code, but that did not work.

Am I supposed to use several files or one ?

Can someone tell me how to layout this code in one file (or multiple files) to make it work?

Comment: Is there a reason you were using a `<javascript>` tag instead of a `<script>` tag?

Comment: If one properly reads the question the desired behavior is implicit and obvious. The question goes: "I am trying to use the sample code given here.". The desired behavior can be none other than the one of the example pointed to. Clicking to read the example will make things clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one .html file. The setup could be like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
    ...
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<javascript>` isn't the right markup for a script element.  Use `<script>` instead.

You can either put your JavaScript in a `<script>` tag on the page, or you can reference an external JavaScript file like this:

```
<script src="path/to/your/script.js"></script>
```